# ASP.NET MVC LINQ Performance issue with two databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working in a ASP.NET MVC application and have two different connections (databases). It's like an application where users do some small exams. On one page, I have to show the user all exams/activities which are done with details: when, which result and all details about the activity/exam.  In the red database are informations only about the result, time, user and activityid - so you can get the activity for that tracking in the other (blue) database. Every activity can be done for maximum 5 times.

I tried several different queries but the performance is very, very slow. Do you have any ideas how could I solve this query and users don't have to wait for 10 seconds on the page?

THANK YOU!

[image]

**EDIT:**

The tracking table (db1, table 1) has now 1732982 records and it is always growing because the users can do the exams when they will. There are currently 1832 activities which come from 110 lessons.

Detailed database picture below (this is what I got, so I have to work with it but I can change ids/pk/fk if needed - or change whatever I need, but it has to stay in two different databases):

[image]

Here is the code which is being used for getting the results for one user. The UserId is sent like a parameter in the function and used in this code.

```
        IList<TrackingCustomModel> result = new List<TrackingCustomModel>();
        using (DATA.examContent.Model ctc = new DATA.examContent.Model()) //first database (activities, lessons)
        {
            using (Model ctx = new Model()) //this is second database (tracking)
            {
                // Get all Activities
                IList<Activity> ac = ctc.Activity.Include("Lesson").ToList();
                char[] trimChars = { '0' };
                IEnumerable<TrackingCustomModel> q;
                    q = from a in ac
                        select new TrackingCustomModel
                        {
                            ActivityId = a.Id,
                            LessonCode = a.Lesson.Code.TrimStart(trimChars),
                            ActivityCode = a.Code.TrimStart(trimChars),
                            ActivityHead = a.Head.Trim()
                        };
                IList<TrackingCustomModel> add = q.ToList<TrackingCustomModel>();
                // Get all Trackings for userId
                IList<Tracking> tr = ctx.Tracking.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).ToList();

                // Join Activites with Tracking of User, and Calculate Scores
                var s = from a in add
                        join t in tr on a.ActivityId equals t.ActivityId
                        orderby t.Timestamp descending
                        select new TrackingCustomModel
                        {
                            ActivityId = a.ActivityId,
                            LessonCode = a.LessonCode,
                            ActivityCode = a.ActivityCode,
                            ActivityHead = a.ActivityHead,
                            Timestamp = DefaultHelper.AdjustDateToLocalTimezone(t.Timestamp),
                            ActivityHits = t.ActivityHits,
                            ActivityMistakes = t.ActivityMistakes,
                            ActivityScore = (t.ActivityHits + t.ActivityMistakes) > 0 ? (String.Format("{0:0%}", (Decimal.Divide(t.ActivityHits, (t.ActivityHits + t.ActivityMistakes))))).ToString() : null
                        };


                // Group the results by Activity and calculate the Activity average

                var group = from t in s
                            group t by t.ActivityId into g
                            select g;
                foreach (IGrouping<Guid, TrackingCustomModel> g in group)
                {
                    TrackingCustomModel thc = (from t in g
                                               where t.ActivityId == g.Key
                                               select t).FirstOrDefault();

                    IList<TrackingCustomModel> multipleTry = (from d in s
                                                              where d.ActivityId == g.Key
                                                              select d).ToList();
                    if (multipleTry.Count > 1)
                    {
                        thc.ActivityDone = multipleTry.Count.ToString();
                        Decimal scoreAsDecimal;
                        Decimal averageScore = 0;
                        foreach (TrackingCustomModel t in multipleTry)
                        {
                            if (t.ActivityHits != 0)
                            {
                                scoreAsDecimal = (Decimal.Divide(t.ActivityHits, (t.ActivityHits + t.ActivityMistakes)));
                                averageScore += scoreAsDecimal;
                            }
                        }
                        averageScore /= multipleTry.Count;
                        if (averageScore != 0)
                        {
                            thc.AverageScore = String.Format("{0:0%}", averageScore).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            thc.AverageScore = "";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thc.ActivityDone = "";
                    }
                    result.Add(thc);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: You need to show the code and queries you are doing. Also any relevant indexes on the tables.

Comment: Because you are using LINQ and two different databases, you may be falling into a common trap of pulling back all the data for each result set into memory and then joining across them with LINQ to objects. Can't tell for sure unless you post a code snippet.

Comment: What is the query that is slow?

Comment: I added some info and the code! Thank you people!

Comment: You should measure the steps in your code, creating `add`, `tr`, and the actual join. Pin down the most time-consuming step. As said, the join is done in memory.

Comment: *but it has to stay in two different databases* If you're using SQL Server then please be aware that it supports cross-database queries and cross-server queries. EF doesn't understand multiple databases and servers, but you can lie to it with synonyms. `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.YourTable FOR YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable`. Or use a view. Cross-server queries can take advantage of statistics to run fairly efficiently, if you set the permissions up right: http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2011/05/optimizer-statistics-on-linked-servers/

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a list of all relevant activities from database 1.
2. Get all Activity info + lesson info from database 2
3. Find what is slow, 1 or 2?

### Slow Activity List Query (Step 1)

Make sure you index whatever your where clauses are. E.g. UserId, maybe including DateTime?

### Slow Activity Info / Lesson Info Query (Step 2)

Make sure Activity.ActiviyID is indexed as that is what you should be searching on in your 2nd query.

Lesson info should be searched by Lesson.LessonID, which should be indexed

If using EF, do a

```
var res = Activities        
    .Include(x => x.Lesson) 
    .Where(x => activityIds.Contains(x.AcitivityID))
    .ToList()
```

from activity to bring the lesson in a single call.

Otherwise If using custom SQL, add a join e.g.

SELECT * FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b ON a.LessonID = b.LessonID

And make sure you map it correctly.

## Other Considerations

- Cache Lesson Info's if this does not change often
- How many Activities/Lessons do you have
- How are you currently querying your objects? Make sure you are not lazily loading the whole tree as this would cause you to hit the database for each unique entity!

### RE: EDIT 1

Not sure how much data you have in your database, but be careful with the following query in your code:

```
 IList<Activity> ac = ctc.Activity.Include("Lesson").ToList();
```

1. This will get **all** Activities in the table
2. The `.Include("Lesson")` will  duplicate Lessons with the same ID potentially causing unfeasibly large amounts of data to be brought back

e.g. If you have 1 lesson, but 50 activities, you will be retrieving a separate instance of Lesson for each of those 50 activities (even though they will be identical).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I edited my question, you can see now in details the database and my code, but I would anyway try your advice and tell you how is it going.